# what is the difference between [optional] keyword with method parameter and default value

Tags: c#, vb.net

I just saw `[optional]` key word in c# when we import `System.Runtime.InteropServices;`! before that I use to set default value to the parameter to make it optional.

I am not getting what is the difference between both patterns, both are doing same any why `[optional]` is specially kept under the `System.Runtime.InteropServices;` like in vb.net it is available without importing it.

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ///new Test3().rrr();
        Test(20);
        Test2(30);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Test(int par1, [Optional] int par2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Par1 -> " + par1);
        Console.WriteLine("Optional par2 -> " + par2.ToString());
    }

    private static void Test2(int par1, int par2 = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Par1 -> " + par1);
        Console.WriteLine("Optional par2 -> " + par2.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `Optional` in that context is not a keyword. Keywords are part of the language and that is not. It's the name of an attribute.

Comment: It's also worth noting that option parameters are not supported by all languages so, before support was added for the second syntax in C#, the first syntax probably didn't actually make the parameter optional. I don't know that for a fact as I never tried it but Office Automation required arguments for all parameters back then so it stands to reason. Such parameters would have been optional if the method was called from VB though, which supported optional parameters the whole time.